# What is the correct notation for null and alternative hypothesis?

Tags: statistics

For each of these questions I have to write the correct notation for null and alternative hypothesis?

1. Are there significant differences in average ages of Daily Express readers across different favourite sections of the
   paper?
   **My solution** : ) Ho: μ ≤ There is no significant difference in average ages of daily express readers across different favourite sections of the paper. 
   Ha: μ > There is significant difference in average ages of daily express readers across different favourite sections of the paper.
   **Is this correct?**
2. Are there significant differences in average annual incomes of Daily Express readers across different favourite sections of the paper?
   **My solution**
   Ho: μ ≤ There is no significant difference in average annual incomes of daily express readers across different favourite sections of the paper. 
   Ha: μ > There is significant difference in average annual incomes of daily express readers across different favourite sections of the paper.
   **Is this correct?**
3. Are there significant differences in the average years of education of Daily Express readers when classified by where they reside; city, town or rural? 
   **My solution**
   Ho: μ ≤ There is no significant difference in average years of education of Daily Express readers when classified by where they reside; city, town or rural?
   Ha: μ > There is significant difference in average years of education of Daily Express readers when classified by where they reside; city, town or rural?
   **Is this correct?**

Answer (score 1):

None of these look correct to me. I would say you are comparing the means across several groups in each case, so I would write for #1 (where $\mu_{S_k}$ is the average age of readers with favorite section $S_k$)

$$H_0 : \mu_{S_1}=\mu_{S_2}=\cdots =\mu_{S_n}$$
$$H_A : \mu_{S_i}\neq\mu_{S_j}\textrm{ for at least one pair } i\neq j$$
and similarly for the other questions.